# Running a defined maintainence dart file when (or after) you call pub get

Tags: dart, dart-pub

I have a dart command prompt file that is a boiler plate function that is required prior to development.  I wanted to run it in when the user runs pub get.

I saw that https://www.dartlang.org/tools/pub/pubspec.html#executables "executables" might be exactly what i want.  I noticed that it has to be in the bin though, so it seems that if i set up:

```
executables:
  admin_script:
```

it would expose `admin_script` to be able to be executed and calls:  bin/admin_script.dart.

The issue is that 1) I wanted this script to be in lib/commmon/ for the time being and run.... and 2) executables exposes it, but doesnt necessarily execute it.

Is there something I am missing which would allow me to do something like:

```
pub get
```

and then it would at the end of `get` call,   `lib/common/admin_script.dart`

**Edit**

As an edit, I was trying to see if there was a way to run this maintenance script either immediately following the pub get.  Not sure if this is valued as being inside of the pubspec.yaml file or if this is something I would want to configure elsewhere in my script.

I was thinking that this would be a good script to run when you open the project, but im not sure if that is also an applicable option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't possible from within pub. It doesn't support any kind of hooks. [This issue](https://github.com/dart-lang/pub/issues/1192) is tracking the ability for packages to provide hooks that are run when they're installed, but I don't think there's an issue for hooks defined by the local package.

Probably the best way to do this right now would be to use a task runner like [hop](https://github.com/kevmoo/hop) to define a task that both runs `pub get` and executes any additional code you need. This has the added benefit of being more explicit than having a hook that runs implicitly.

As an aside, executables stored bin/ and exposed through the pubspec are intended to be *public-facing*: they're for users of your package to execute. If you want an executable that's only run in your package, that should go in the tool/ directory. See [the package layout conventions](https://www.dartlang.org/tools/pub/package-layout.html) for more details.

Comment: Thank you.  That was informative, and gives me an idea of what to do.